# Should I use Backbone.emulateHTTP or php file_get_contents

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone JS with a CodeIgniter backend.

It seems I have two choices:

- Set backbone to:

  ```
  Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
  Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
  ```

  Which sends everything as Form Data, which I can pick up on the server with

  ```
  $this->input->post()
  ```
- or I can leave Backbone on normal settings, in which case it gets sent in the request payload and I have to use:

  ```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  ```

Is there a right answer to this? Does the first one mean it's not technically RESTful? And does that matter??

Comment: If you are using sessions the ship on technically RESTful has sailed

Answer (score 0):

I've recently finished a backbone / ci (restful api) application and grabbed all my data using codeigniter's $this->input function. you shouldn't have any problems.